# Question about seemingly non-interchangeable nested limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the following functions:
$$\phi(x,n)=\Bigl{[} \cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}) \Bigr{]}^n$$
and
$$g(x) = \exp\Bigl{(} -\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr{)}$$
It seems that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\phi(x,n) = g(x)$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$; that is,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\Bigl{[} \cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}) \Bigr{]}^n} = \exp\Bigl{(} -\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr{)}$$
I believe this can be shown using the Maclaurin series of $\cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})$ taken to second order and the Maclaurin series of $\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$. The result seems to imply that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\phi(x,n)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}g(x)=0$$

However, if we reverse the order of the limits, we have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\phi(x,n)}$ cannot exist, because $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\phi(x,n)}$ does not converge. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, there always exist $y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ greater than $x$ such that $\phi(y,n)=1$ and $\phi(z,n)=-1$.

In light of limits usually being interchangeable, is it correct to conclude that one nested limit exists and the other does not? Or does the non-existence of one imply the non-existence of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is right. Limits to infinity are not in fact "usually" interchangeable, and the following much simpler example illustrates this: take $\phi(x, n)$ to be the function which is equal to $1$ if $|x| \le n$ and $0$ otherwise. So in other words $\phi(x, n)$ is a rectangle of height $1$ and width $2n$ centered at $0$.

Pointwise, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(x, n) = 1$ for all $x$, since the rectangle eventually becomes arbitrarily large and overtakes a fixed value of $x$, and so $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(x, n) = 1$. But $\lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x, n) = 0$ for all $n$, since for every fixed $n$ we eventually escape the rectangle, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x, n) = 0$.

Loosely speaking, if you think of two-variable functions like $\phi(x, n)$ as "infinitely tall and infinitely wide matrices," with say $x$ labeling the columns and $n$ labeling the rows, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(x, n)$ describes what happens if you go "infinitely far down, then infinitely far to the right," whereas $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x, n)$ describes what happens if you go "infinitely far to the right, then infinitely far down." There is no reason these should be the same in general. The $\phi(x, n)$ defined above is basically a giant lower triangular matrix, designed so that if you go "infinitely far down" you always get $1$, but if you go "infinitely far to the right" you always get $0$.

In a positive direction see the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).